# Issue getting Metamask account using Web3 1.1.0

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I am working on a React app which uses a library that has Web3 as a dependency. I had previously been able to the get the current Metamask address with the following code:

```
 const injectedWeb3 = window.web3 || undefined;

 this.state = {
      web3: injectedWeb3
    };

  getAccount() {
    const { web3 } = this.state;
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0]) return web3.eth.accounts[0];
    throw new Error('Your MetaMask is locked. Unlock it to continue.');
  }
```

Then I updated that library to its latest version which changed it's Web3 dependency to Web3 1.0 . Now when I run the exact same code I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined 
TypeError: e is not a function[Learn More]
```

Any thoughts as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 4):

Found a workaround for this, you can use window.ethereum.enable() and attach it to the web3.eth.defaultAccount variable,

```
loadAccount : async () =>{
       window.ethereum.enable().then((account) =>{
           const defaultAccount = account[0]
           web3.eth.defaultAccount = defaultAccount

       })
    }
```

you can then access the Account ID / Address by using `web3.eth.defaultAccount`

Answer (score 0):

Web3.js v1 has many differences from the previous version.
Account request is now asynchronous:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(it => {
            account = it[0];
       ...
});
```

If you need to wait for the operation to complete, use **await**

**update**

```
async function getAccount() {
    var account = 0;
    if (window.ethereum) { // for modern DApps browser
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            await ethereum.enable();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }else if (web3) { // for old DApps browser
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }

    if(window.web3!== 'undefined'){
            try {
                await window.web3.eth.getAccounts().then(it => {
                    account = it[0];
             }); 
    }
    return account;
}
```

Comment: I got the same error when I tried your code above. So far I am able to get 'web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);' to display the account in the console. But when I even try 'web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);' . It says the function is undefined and that 'callback is not a function'.

Comment: There is a 'null' before it outputs the array in the console when I use 'web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);' . If that is of any significance?

Comment: What is the result of this code:
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(it => {
            console.log(it[0]);
});

Comment: Another question - is injectedWeb3 defined?

Web3js v1 is required to request metamask for permission to grant access rights to web3

Comment: The result of the code snippet you put in the comments i:  TypeError: web3.eth.getAccounts(...) is undefined[Learn More] 
TypeError: callback is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: The injectedWeb3 is being defined as follows: new Web3(injectedWeb3.currentProvider); . I updated that in the code of the question.

Comment: I updated the answer above, added the code to initialize web3 in version 1.
new Web3 (injectedWeb3.currentProvider); now may not work.
https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Comment: My issue is not with the Injecting of web3. I actually had a look at the 'Truffle React Box' and adopted their implementation which uses the same approach as you have above but I still get the same issue. I can run 'web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);' and get the answer but I simply cannot run ' const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();' or use'web3.eth.getAccounts().then();' without getting an 'Callback is not a function' error.

Comment: Could it be because I have all these functions inside the React Class constructor? In the React-Box (Truffle) they have it all in componentDidMount().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91356/discussion-between-vasay-and-phoenixson).